# How would I go about resizing my / partition and installing a 2nd Linux distribution so I can dual boot?

Tags: linux, partition, dual-boot

I have two disks in my system that are currently running Debian Bookworm.

- `disk 1`

  1. `/boot/efi`
  2. `/`
  3. `swap`
- `disk 2`

  1. `/home`

I want to:

1. resize `/` and split it into two partitions such that `disk 1` looks like:

   1. `/boot/efi`
   2. `/` = the current Debian install
   3. `/` = 2nd Linux distribution install
   4. `swap`
2. the current Debian install would stay on the first half of the now split `/`
3. install a 2nd Linux distribution on the 2nd half of the now split `/`
4. have grub show both so I can pick which one I want to boot
5. ideally use the same `/boot/efi` and `/swap` with both distributions

Is this possible? How would I go about it?

Comment: It's possible and actually mandatory to use the same ESP because you're asking about a single drive. The second installation should also pick up and use the swap partition.

Comment: I would not suggest sharing /home. But you can have a data partition with just your data, no user settings from /home and share the data partition. During install you just choose your new / partition for /. In Ubuntu it is called Something Else or none of the auto install options that may erase, or auto install along side resizing a random partition.

Comment: I see. That is an idea....